# Let a,b,c be integers. Prove that if a|c and b|c, then either a|b or b|a.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

> Let a,b,c be integers. Prove that if a|c and b|c, then either a|b or b|a.

Any ideas? (Suggested proof by contradiction). Not really sure how to go about this.

Comment: The property is false. If $a=2, b=3, c=6$, then $2\mid 6$ and $3\mid 6$, but $2\not\mid 3$ and $3\not\mid 2$.

Comment: Ah, well that clears things up... Thanks haha. Do you have any suggestions on finding counter-examples in these types of questions?

Comment: This one was simple, since I know that if $a,b$ are relatively prime, we can still create a $c$ such that $c=abm$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z$. Any relatively prime numbers $a,b$ would give a counterexample in this case.

Comment: To clarify: any coprime integers $a,b$ have the property that neither $a\mid b$ nor $b\mid a$, but we can always create a $c$ such that $c=abm$ for some integer $m$. Therefore, any coprime integers would give us a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is, in fact, false.

To prove a statement is false, you need only provide one counter-example. (One counter-example suffices, because the claim is being made about any/all integers $a, b, c$ such that $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$. So if you find any particular triplet such that $a, b, c$ are integers and $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$, but it is not the case that $a\mid b$ or $b\mid a$, the claim is in fact false.)

E.g., Suppose $a = 3, b=4, c= 12$. Then indeed, $3\mid 12\, $ and $\,4\mid 12,\,$ but $3$ does *not* divide $4$, *nor* does $4$ divide $3$.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any advice/techniques that would help in identifying counter-examples?

Comment: Note that $a\mid b$ or $b\mid a$ requires that $\gcd(a, b) = b$ or $\gcd(a, b) = a$, respectively. For any $a \neq 1, b\neq 1$ such that $(a, b) = 1$ will *fail* to satisfy the conclusion. So I pick $a, b$ that are coprime. Then I look for some $c$ such that $c = abk$ for some integer $k$ so that the antecedent of the implication is satisfied. Any implication $p\rightarrow q$ with p true and q false, as in the example provided in my post, is necessarily false.

Comment: [I don't know if you got pinged.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937815/proving-cardinality-of-the-reals-and-the-cross-product-of-the-reals#comment1934553_937815)

Comment: @Asaf Yes, I got pinged. I just answered your comment. Note also that if I had remembered the "gold-star" effect, I would have thought twice about voting to reopen.